# omnicppcomplete not supporting all forms of const

Tags: c++, vim, omnicppcomplete

I have omnicppcomplete working fine except once in a while it won't complete some of the variables methods/members.  I finally got annoyed enough to dig into why and I believe the reason is that omnicppcomplete does support the syntax "Foo const & foo" in function arguments.

For example, if I have a function defined as:

```
int foo( Bar const & b ){
}
```

I won't be able to get completion information when I later type "b.".  However if I change the signature to:

```
int foo( const Bar & b ){
}
```

I will be able to get completion information when I type "b.".  It seems to only be in function argument lists because I tried simply defining a variable within the function with the signature "Bar const & bref" and I was able to get completion information for bref.

I would be surprised if this is an actual limitation of omnicppcomplete; anyone have any thoughts on whether or not this is a bug and/or if there is a workaround for it?  Changing the coding style does not seem like a reasonable solution.

Comment: Wow, that's lame! Especially since the former is the more consistent syntax (though of course the latter is no less correct, strictly speaking).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a limitation in omnicppcomplete, but I pulled up the vim debugger and found it.

Open up autoload/omni/cpp/utils.vim, go to line 518, should look like this:

```
  for token in tokens
        if state==0
            if token.value=='>'
                let parenGroup = token.group
                let state=1
            elseif token.kind == 'cppWord'
                let szResult = token.value.szResult
                let state=2
            elseif index(['*', '&'], token.value)<0 "This is line 518
                break
            endif
```

And change that line to:

```
 elseif token.value != 'const' && index(['*', '&'], token.value)<0
```

Or, here's the vim commands to do it =):

```
/index(\['\*', '&'],<CR>itoken.value != 'const' &&<ESC>:w
```

I'll try submitting this to the maintainer of omnicppcomplete, but it's kind of hackish, dunno if it'll get in.  Might've been able to check if token.kind == 'cppKeyword', but I figured I'd err on the side of changing the least.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had given up hope on anyone answering.  
On an unrelated note, did the bounty entice you to look in some way.  I never thought the bounty thing was useful; this is the first time it worked.  Just more for my curiosity.

Comment: I don't think the bounty really mattered that much to me directly, but it did make the question show up on the featured questions list for C++, which is where I saw it.  It's a nice perk, though. =)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Having experienced issues with omnicppcomplete, I searched for an alternative and found [clang complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) which uses clang's metadata output (that is intended for such purposes). I works extremely well and provided your code compiles, it will understand everything.

Comment: Yeah I saw clang complete but unfortunately I don't have access to clang on all of my development servers...